# Modify then sell another person's code

Tags: legal

I am working, with a co-author, on a data modeling toolbox that will someday be sold. Part of the functionality is the extremely common PCA, which we are doing in a more robust way. Thus, we need a PCA function that has the usual algorithm with some modifications. For non-commercial peer-review academic research, I could easily find PCA code that is already written, modify it to suit my needs and use it, citing the author in my research.

My co-author insists that in this commercial venture, it is entirely appropriate to do the same thing. We can take another author's copyrighted code (ex "Copyright (c) 1997 by blah blah blah", not necessarily a GNU license), modify it to suit our needs, and distribute it with the toolbox we are selling. He says that as long as we cite the original author, it's entirely acceptable.

I'm just as strenuously insisting this is not legal, but have been unable to find straightforward documentation. Can someone point me to unambiguous documentation of this?

Comment: depends on the actual license if there is no clear license you don't have permission, (consult a lawyer)

Comment: You should not ask for legal advice on Stack Exchange, or the Internet as a whole, for that matter.

Comment: This depends not only on the license of the code, but also on the country where you live and the countries where you are going to sell your programs. I can understand that you don't want to pay a lawyer just for a discussion with your co-author, but I guess googling for "copyright law" will find you some arguments.

Comment: The question of if something is legal or not is best answered by someone versed in contract and intellectual property law within your jurisdiction.  As programmers, this is not something that we are familiar with and cannot give you good advice for the problem you are having.  Copying copyrighted code (even with credit) may open you up to copyright infringement - be it open source or not.  **Talk to a lawyer**

Comment: Though I agree with everyone here regarding the fact you need to talk to a lawyer, I will add you appear to be missing the term from your vocabulary this act is known by; when you use someone else's code or DLL or works of any sort in your system and distribute them as a part of your system, this is known as "redistributing". That is the key legal term to comb licenses and speak to a lawyer about, the reidistribution rights granted by any license or applicable laws.

Comment: Thanks for all the obvious "contact a lawyer" comments (duhh) when I'm asking simply for where to find existing documentation of an extremely clear-cut issue (it's illegal to take someone else's intellectual property and sell it as my own, period).

Comment: @Dr.Drew it isn't clear cut.  It depends on the license of the original material and what license you are releasing your software under. Is the IP copied as code? statically linked as a library? dynamically linked?  It depends on where you live. IP (it isn't just copyrights that get involved) law in the US is different than in the EU.

Comment: @Dr.Drew - Yes its illegal to take a peice of copyrighted material ( the code ) and attempt to sell it without a license.  If you don't own the copyright to the code you cannot sell it.  Modifying it is not enough to gain ownership of the copyright.  **You can always write your own and do whatever you want.**

Comment: I closed this question because legal questions are off topic here, and that is exactly what this question is.  Software developers are not qualified to answer this for your specific situation.

Answer (score 8):

Contact the author of the code you intend to modify and ask for permission in writing to do what your partner wants.  That won't cover you, but a strongly worded "don't modify my code" letter might convince your partner that this is a bad idea.

As the many comments have pointed out, asking for legal advice from a bunch of strangers who don't claim to be lawyers (let alone live in your country) is a bad idea.

If you're going to make anything more than beer money it will be very important to be able to prove that you have clear rights (either ownership or appropriate [FOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) license) to everything.

**Talk to a local lawyer**

Spending money on a lawyer is cheaper than defending (or worse, losing) a lawsuit.

Comment: +1. But if the original author gives you permission in writing, it does cover you.

Comment: @MarkJ - probably, but that may depend on what country the OP is in.

Comment: Sorry, but how does that depend on the country? Are you suggesting there's a country where a copyright holder can't grant permission to use their material?

Comment: @MarkJ: Sure.  E.g., I believe that in the US, some encryption code is classified as a munition.

Comment: Ok, that's an interesting example, but the OP is not talking about an encryption algorithm as far as I can tell. OP has just asked for a reference to prove that they can't just adapt someone else's code.

Comment: @MarkJ "Public Domain" isn't universally recognized across all nations. Something that is in the public domain can't be used without a license in those nations that don't recognize public domain (and that requires someone holding the copyright to be able to license it).  See [opensource.org FAQ on public domain](http://opensource.org/faq#public-domain).

Comment: @MarkJ: Taking legal advise from strangers on the internet is questionable. Giving it more so, especially as you are wrong. A letter that "Gives you permision in writing" is quite a different proposition a contract that a lawyer will draw up. Will that permission spell out liabilty, accountability, declare right to give permission........ Think a poker game, "I'll see your letter and raise you a contract"

Comment: @mattnz a good point which I already addressed in my answer below, where I suggest getting the author to provide the code under an unrestrictive open source license to avoid paying for a lawyer.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to contact a lawyer for *every* question about law! Some issues are very straightforward.

You don't say where you live, which makes it hard to give an appropriate reference. Here's one for where *I* live: a UK [government website on intellectual property law](http://www.ipo.gov.uk/types/copy/c-applies/c-literary.htm). Summary quote

> You may need to get permission from a copyright owner if you wish to copy written work [including software] in any way, unless any exceptions apply [they don't in your case]

Search for a website from your own government for a reference for your own country.

Going beyond the question. You *might* want to ask a lawyer to write an agreement for the original author to sign, to be sure it will stand up in court, or just choose an unrestrictive open source license like MIT.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the modification that's the problem -- modifications are of course your own work, and you own that part. The problem is the unmodified code, and the fact that you're basing your work on someone else's in the first place.

**If your partner thinks it's okay to use someone else's work without permission, he doesn't understand what copyright means.**

May you reprint a copyrighted book and sell it<sup>*</sup>, even with proper attribution? No.

May you re-record a copyrighted song and sell it<sup>*</sup>, even with proper attribution? No.

**May you re-use copyrighted code and sell it<sup>*</sup>, even with proper attribution? No.**

One has to wonder how your partner would feel about someone taking *your* code and selling it without permission.

<sup>*</sup><sub>without permission of the author</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think that it entirely depends on what you define as modifying. If you change his code but leave most of the work intact, you're basing your copyrighted code on his copyrighted code.

If however you take his code and use it as inspiration for your code then your code is not based on his copyrighted code but on his (patented) implementation.
Basically: write your own implementation of what the original author did. Shouldn't be hard because you can use his code as inspiration.

Comment: Thanks Pieter, this is actually useful.  The modification I need to make is essentially a one-line call to my own code, inserted in the existing code.  Hence, the resulting function would be 99% the other author's.  I'll have to take this "inspiration" route, but the issue with my co-author will come up again, and I don't want to fight about this every time.  Hence, my request for documentation that my stance is correct.

Comment: Adding a one-line call is  not enough to go down the "inspiration route".